# Remove leading comma in header when using pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

By default to_csv writes a CSV like

```
,a,b,c
0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

But I want it to write like this:

```
a,b,c
0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

How do I achieve this? I can't set `index=False` because I want to preserve the index. I just want to remove the leading comma.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)), columns = ['a','b','c'])
df.to_csv("test.csv") # this results in the first example above.
```

Comment: You do not want to remove that leading comma or all other columns are shifted to left since csv is a **c**omma-**s**eparated **v**alues text file.

Comment: @Parfait The second dataframe in my example above works perfectly well. Give it a try. `pd.read_csv("test.csv")` (where test.csv is the second example).

Comment: Carefully look at that desired result which is exactly what I mention. Column A is no longer aligned to original values but shifted to left and then you have the last column without a header!

Comment: It's implied that the index is unnamed, and `pd.read_csv` interprets that implication correctly. I know this is certainly not best practice, and I don't recommend anyone do it this way, but I needed to do it this way for some legacy reasons. @Parfait

Comment: Understood but do note, other than `pandas`, reading this csv (per accepted answer below) in other applications/languages will result in shifted columns. I had a feeling this was an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your real question should have been handling the *legacy reasons*! I have yet to met a use case to break best practices. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: @Parfait 100% agree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible by write only columns without index first and then data without header in append mode:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)), columns = ['a','b','c'], index=list('XYZ'))

pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns).to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
#alternative for empty df
#df.iloc[:0].to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
df.to_csv("test.csv", header=None, mode='a')

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print (df)
     a    b    c
X  0.0  0.0  0.0
Y  0.0  0.0  0.0
Z  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply set a name for your index: `df.index.name = 'blah'`. This name will appear as the first name in the headers.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)), columns = ['a','b','c'])
df.index.name = 'my_index'
print(df.to_csv())
```

yields

```
my_index,a,b,c
0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

However if (as per your comment) you wish to have 3 coma-separated names in the headers while there are 4 coma-separated values in the rows of the csv, you'll have to handcraft it. It will NOT be compliant with any csv standard format though.

Comment: Well I want the header to be "a,b,c", and not "my_index,a,b,c" ? @Parfait

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, try reseting the index so it becomes a column in data frame, named *index*. This works with multiple indexes as well.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
```